# Найти перестановку

Tags: javascript, строки, классы

Есть форма с двумя input, в которую будут введены 2 номера телефонов. В строках есть pattern на ввод 12 символов, не больше ни меньше. Необходимо проверить не только схожесть номеров, но и в случае чего различие.

**Пример ввода:
79031234567 - номер 1
79691234567 - номер 2**

Как по итогу вывести alert, что номер отличается на 2 цифры (69)

Имеющийся код на проверку схожести:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function Go() {
    var x1=+document.getElementById('text1').value
    var x2=+document.getElementById('text2').value
    if (x1==x2) {
        alert("Номера совпали!")
    } else {
        alert("Номера разные")
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Пройтись одним циклом по двум строкам и сравнивать каждый символ одной строки (номер 1) с соответственным символом другой строки (номер 2).
Как-то так:

```
function GetDifference(phone1, phone2, isDigitsOfPhone1) {
    var result = "";

    for(var i = 0; i < MaxLength; i++)
        if(phone1[i] != phone2[i])
            result += isDigitsOfPhone1 ? phone1[i] : phone2[i];

    return result;
}
```

`isDigitsOfPhone1` - флаг, который говорит какие цифры отправить в результат. Если `true`, то будут выводиться цифры первого телефона. Если `false`, то второго.
Для Вашего случая:

```
alert(GetDifference(x1, x2, false));
```